# Serviço de Bluetooth para comunicar aplicação Java Desktop e Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Eu estou fazendo tcc, o projeto é criar uma aplicação java desktop e fazer com que essa se comunique com um aplicativo android. Como essa comunicação será em uma sala por exemplo, sempre no mesmo ambiente, pensei em usar o Bluetooth. Fiz um teste com o BlueCove em java, porém é preciso instalar o driver de bluetooh na máquina. Minha dúvida é a seguinte, caso a aplicação for rodar em sistemas operacionais diferentes ou o mesmo sistema mas com versões diferentes como tratar o problema da instalação do driver de bluetooh ? Caso a máquina seja antiga e não possua uma placa para aceitar o bluetooh. Até onde seria viável usá-lo ? Obrigada.

Comment: Você pode tentar fazer a aplicação java instalar o driver na máquina. Sua aplicação pode ter um pacote de drivers junto com ela para reconhecer o S.O. e instalar o driver adequado, ou, a Aplicação pode reconhecer o S.O. e baixar o driver correto da internet para instalá-lo. Nunca mexi com isso, mas acho que seria assim :)

Comment: Que show @Douglas, gostei da ideia. Vou fazer essa tentativa. Obrigada.